# How to import into excel data from table on PHP website

Tags: vba, excel

I really have no idea how to get data from that website using excel import from web

website address:
http://www.scramble.nl/military-database/usaf

serch for serial for example: **62-3578**

gives results in table:

Scramble Database - Query Results:

**Serial:     62-3578

Type:       KC-135R

CN:         18561/T0629

Unit:       141st ARS**

is it possible to  search for data using vba excel for that type of website?

In response to the recent comment, I am not expecting that somebody will code everything for me, I have used this site before and I am aware of it, but this time I am stuck with this problem right after start...

This is the code I started from

```
      Sub Get_scramble_data()
  '
  ' Get_scramble_data Macro
  '

 '
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.scramble.nl/index.php?option=com_mildb&view=search", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "index.php?option=com_mildb&view=search"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With
  End Sub
```

but the next step requires to manually insert value, for example **62-3578**  in serial field and click search then I was trying to grab data from search result in newly created table and that VBA code is not working, I am getting message: " This Web query returned no data "

Comment: Yes it's possible. One possible solution is to use Excel with VBA to control Internet Explorer to perform the search, wait for the page to load, then scrape the data from the Table in the site. Typically SO is used to help with specific problems with code, so give something a try and come back. The community is always happy to help.

Comment: @RyanWildry I tried but after selecting table web data import doesn't even start...

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the tour and how to ask. Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.

Comment: @Trimax I am fully aware that this is not the site to get full code... hence my edit above, maybe I was not explaining it right and I should have added the code in the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an X/Y problem. You *think* you can use `QueryTables` for this, but you can't. So you're looking for the wrong solution.

> I really have no idea how to get data from that website using excel import from web

I'm not writing the code for you, but here are the *ideas* and I'll leave it up to you to implement the code.

1. This can't be done via `QueryTables`, so you'll need to automate your interaction with the website, either via `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` or via `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTPRequest")` objects, or similar (e.g., Selenium Web Driver).
2. You'll need to understand how to get a handle on the the desired element (the field in which you will enter the search term). The methods available will vary by how you implement (1) above. If IE, you'll need to use something like `GetElementByID` (if there's an `ID` for the element) or brute force iteration over the tag name and using appropriate logic to identify the correct element. Google [VBA get element on website](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&espv=2&q=vba+get+element+on+website&oq=vba+get+element+on+website).
3. You'll need to use similar logic to get a handle on the appropriate "Search" button.
4. Once you have a handle on the input field, you can write the value "62-3578" into the field. Google [VBA enter data to website](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&espv=2&q=vba+enter+data+to+website).
5. Then you automate the `Click` or `Submit` event of the button or form. Google [VBA Click button on webpage](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&espv=2&q=vba+click+button+on+webpage).
6. You'll need to wait for the page to reload using a Ready Waiting loop.
7. You'll need to then identify the element which contains the *Table* of data on the page, and parse the values accordingly, in order to drop them in to your worksheet.

That is the basic ep-by-step. It's totally possible. If you didn't know *how* to proceed, now, you should have some ideas of where to begin, and this should give you ideas about what topics you need to search for in order to implement a good solution.

**NOTE** If you get stuck on *any* of these steps, that should be a separate, focused & specific question. You'll have better luck getting answers if you are asking questions about specific problems, rather than questions which appear to be asking for a full solution.

My advice is to break this up one step at a time. Figure out step 1. If you get stuck, have errors or problems, ask a question. Once you get that working, try to implement step 2. If you get stuck, ask a question, etc...

Comment: Great hints, like I said I am not looking for someone to write a full code for me, just a pointers which way to go because I didn't know that QueryTables is a not the right way to do this, thanks again this should keep me busy for next few days...